# Cannot install Debian packages

Tags: debian, software-installation, php

I'm running a Docker container and having trouble installing packages. I have tried various methods of fixing the issue after a few hours of Googling but nothing seems to be working. I don't understand enough about Linux to figure out what is going wrong.

Specifically I am trying to install the package `php-common` with apt-get and I keep getting `E: Package 'php-common' has no installation candidate` response. This response happens for a lot of packages I try to install though and I don't know why.

The Docker image I am using the official php image `php7.1-apache`, based on Debian 10 (Buster).

Running `uname -a` prints: `Linux 1fa97a139193 4.9.184-linuxkit #1 SMP Tue Jul 2 22:58:16 UTC 2019 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

This is the contents of my `/etc/apt/sources.list` file:

```
# deb http://snapshot.debian.org/archive/debian/20190910T000000Z buster main
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian buster main
# deb http://snapshot.debian.org/archive/debian-security/20190910T000000Z buster/updates main
deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates main
# deb http://snapshot.debian.org/archive/debian/20190910T000000Z buster-updates main
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates main
```

Output of `cat /etc/os-release`

```
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="10"
VERSION="10 (buster)"
VERSION_CODENAME=buster
ID=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.debian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://www.debian.org/support"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.debian.org/"
```

Output of `cat /etc/issue`

```
Debian GNU/Linux 10 \n \l
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to the Unix and Linux stack exchange site! Please review the [Help Center](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help) for more information on how to use this site. To get to your question, could you please edit your post to include the following details to clarify your post: What is the output of `cat /etc/os-release` or `cat /etc/issue`? What is the results of `apt-cache search php-common`? Please run these commands from within your container. Thank you.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. I edited the post to include the output of `cat /etc/os-release` and `cat /etc/`

Comment: Running `apt-cache search php-common` prints nothing

Answer (score 2):

I don’t know where the `php7.1-apache` image is hosted, so I wasn’t able to check with that; but I suspect that your problem stems from the fact that the majority of Debian-based images ship with no repository indexes, so `apt-get install` won’t work initially.

One of the first steps when using such a container is to run `apt-get update`. Once that’s done, `apt-get install` should work, assuming the packages you want are available in the configured repositories.

Regarding your `sources.list`, if you’re trying to install packages from Debian 10, I highly recommend starting with a Debian 10-based image rather than an image based on an older release. You could start with `debian:10`...

Comment: Hey, I tried running `apt-get update` already. It did fix a previous issue, but not this one unfortunately

Comment: Also I am running buster, my mistake, I included more information above.

Comment: @Jasen sorry, I misread your comment earlier; my last paragraph was based on the mention in the original question that the image was based on Jessie.

Comment: @Marcus that’s rather odd! If `apt-get update` completed without error, `apt-get install php-common` should work just fine — `php-common` is [present in Debian 10](https://packages.debian.org/buster/php-common).

Comment: @StephenKitt Yeah I thought it was pretty strange. Do I maybe have the wrong repo URL? `http://deb.debian.org/debian`??

Comment: Yes, that’s the correct URL. That uses a CDN, so you might end up on a bad mirror (hopefully temporarily). You could try [a local mirror](https://www.debian.org/mirror/list) instead, and see if that works...

Answer (score 0):

This is intentional, as stated in ["E: Package 'php-XXX' has no installation candidate"](https://github.com/docker-library/docs/tree/master/php#e-package-php-xxx-has-no-installation-candidate).

> The *proper* solution to this error is to either use `FROM debian:XXX` and install Debian's PHP packages directly, or to use `docker-php-ext-install`, `pecl`, and/or `phpize` to install the necessary additional extensions and utilities.